# malloc on char** read and write Error

Tags: c, malloc

I have an char** stringList, in which i want to write Strings of unknown size and count.

at some point i have the following code:

```
static char** stringList;
static int laenge=0;
static int size=0;

void getInput(){
    char input[FILENAME_MAX];
    int zeilen=10;
    int counter=0;
    stringList = (char**) malloc(zeilen*sizeof(char*));
    size = zeilen*sizeof(char*);
        while(fgets(input, FILENAME_MAX , stdin) != NULL)
        {
        if (strlen(input) <= 100){
            stringList[counter] = (char*) malloc(strlen(input));
            size += strlen(input);
            if (stringList[counter] == NULL){
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            strcpy(stringList[counter],input);
            counter++;
            laenge++;
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr,"String longer than 100 characters\n");
        }
        if (counter==zeilen){
            zeilen +=10;
            stringList = (char**) realloc(stringList,size+10*sizeof(char));
            if (stringList == NULL){
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
        }
}
```

If needed I increase the size of stringList, to make it able to store more Strings.

Valgrind gives me a writeerror on line 1 and 5, also a readerror on line 2.

Comment: Have you `malloc`ed enough memory to `stringList` itself? (Also, `malloc`ing in line 1 and assigning in line 5 leaks the `malloc`ed memory.)

Comment: Give us a minimal example code please we don't know the type of input ect...

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to allocate your buffer of strings and verify that `counter` doesn't increase more than `max_strings`:

```
char** stringList = (char**)malloc(max_strings*sizeof(char*));
```

Line (1) should be (strlen instead of sizeof):

```
stringList[counter] = (char*) malloc(1+strlen(input));
```

Line (5) should be (you have to copy the string to the allocated memory):

```
strcpy(stringList[counter], input);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allocate more memory for your `char **stringList`, you can use [`realloc()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/)

**BTW**

this

```
stringList[counter] = input;
```

should be changed to

```
strcpy(stringList[counter], input);
```

Otherwise the allocation memory with

```
stringList[counter] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(input));
```

will have no sense

Comment: stringList is malloc'd with sizeof(char)*10.

Comment: each time it gets full i realloc(stringList, sizeof(stringList)+10*sizeof(char)) ... as the first dimension does not store string, but only manages the lines, in which strings are stored its not that big on size.

Comment: so if you reached 10 element whenn you filling it and you want more memory for it you can use realloc(). it will allow to allocate more data for stringList. seee the link to realloc() page in the answer. there is an example of how use realloc()

Comment: @TorhanBartel it should be `sizeof(char *)*10` and not `sizeof(char)*10`

Comment: @TorhanBartel sizeof(stringList) will not return the old size allocate by malloc/realloc. it will return always 4. because stringList is a pointer and the size of pointer in 32 bit systems is 4

Comment: @TorhanBartel I suggest to you to keep the size of your stringList array into a separate variable and increment it each time you use realloc()

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(input))` looks wrong.  Shouldn't it be `malloc(strlen(input)+1)`

Comment: @simonc, I can not confirm, The OP does not show the whole code and especially the input declaration. it could be defined as `char input[10];` and in this way the `malloc(sizeof(input))` is valid but not optimized

Comment: Fair point but I don't agree with your decision.  Recommending use of `strlen` is guaranteed to work.  Recommending use of `sizeof` may work or may cause hard to debug memory corruption.  I'd always recommend use of `strlen` for beginner-level questions.  There will be plenty of time for the o/p to learn about options for performance tuning later.

Comment: Ok this migtht sound weird... im working on another comuter via ssh, therefore using the nano editor. how can i paste the complete code, without having to retype it?

Comment: @simonc Personally I will recommend strlen too. but this was not the OP question. so that's why I did not change it. the OP question was how to allocate more memory for stringList

Comment: ok... posted complete method... stringList is a static variable

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you want an array to store an undetermined numbers of element (`char*` in that case) you should use **linked list** (there are plenty of tutorial and code samples across the net) and not a simple `char**` because useless use of `realloc` is a bad practice (internally `realloc` allocate a new buffer and then copy everything from the old buffer into the new one).

However if you want to keep your `char**` there's some things you need to change:

- First, you should check the return value of `malloc` the first time you call it
- Second thing, you should do that to add a `'\0'` character at the end of your `char*` (in order to run through it later):

  ```
  stringList[counter] = (char *)malloc(strlen(input) + 1); // I add "+ 1"
  stringList[counter][strlen(input)] = '\0'; // 0 works also
  ```
- Third thing, you should remove `size` variable because it's useless
- Fourth thing, inside your `if (counter==zeilen)` block, the second line should be :

  ```
  stringList = (char**) realloc(stringList,zeilen*sizeof(char*)); // I replaced char by char * and used zeilen instead of "size+10"
  ```

  Little tip if you don't want to have that problem, you can replace `char*` by 
  `*stringList`, and `char` by `*(stringList[counter])` in the different `sizeof` inside the malloc/realloc of your code.

Moreover, laenge isn't use in your exemple and global variable are bad practice too.